# Create a binary table based on decimal table data - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I wish to convert a table of decimal numbers to a binary. I wrote this code:

```
clc;
clear all;

binTable = [];
ID = {'1';'2';'3';'4';'5'};
C1 = [1;2;3;4;5];
C2 = [10;11;12;13;14];
C3 = [26;27;28;29;30];

decTable = table(ID,C1,C2,C3);

for i = 1:width(decTable)
    for j = 2:height(decTable)
        binTable(i,j) = dec2bin(decTable(i,j));
    end
end
```

but I get this error:

```
Error using dec2bin (line 25)
D must be numeric.

Error in Untitled1 (line 13)
        binTable(i,j) = dec2bin(decTable(i,j));
```

How can I solve it as the decTable(i,j) is table class?

Comment: Use curly braces to get the numerical data in the table: `dec2bin(decTable{i,j});`

Comment: I get this error:  `Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 1-by-4.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want. You have to put the char array that `dec2bin` returns in a cell again, which you can then put into the binTable.

```
ID = {'1';'2';'3';'4';'5'};
C1 = [1;2;3;4;5];
C2 = [10;11;12;13;14];
C3 = [26;27;28;29;30];

decTable = table(ID,C1,C2,C3);
binTable = table(ID,ID,ID,ID); % init table with all char arrays that has same size as decTable

for i = 1:height(decTable)
    for j = 2:width(decTable)
        binTable(i,j) = {dec2bin(decTable{i,j})};
    end
end
```